# How to simplify an expression by collecting like terms?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify an equation in terms of $x$. And I tried the `Simplify` and `Collect` functions by assuming $x$ is positive real. But the result does not collect the $x$ together.

```
a = x^4;
b = (y/x^(3/8))^(7/9);
Assuming[{x > 0, x ∈ Reals}, Simplify[a b, x]]
Collect[a b, x] //. Assuming -> x > 0
```

> $\text{True}^4 \left(\frac{y}{\text{True}^{3/8}}\right)^{7/9}$
>
> $x^4 \left(\frac{y}{x^{3/8}}\right)^{7/9}$

Does anyone know how to do it correctly?

Comment: `% // PowerExpand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appropriate functionality to use here is `PowerExpand`.

```
a = x^4;
b = (y/x^(3/8))^(7/9);
a b // PowerExpand
```

> x^(89/24) y^(7/9)

Answer (score 1):

Simplify has wrong syntax:  `Simplify[expression, conditions]`

Then:

```
Simplify[a b, {x > 0}]
```

> x^(89/24) y^(7/9)